# Android - notification when field in database changes

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, notifications

I am pretty new to programming.
I am making an application for android that gets data about events from database, users may add new events, but they have "status" set as 0, so I have to change them in phpmyadmin to 1 to make them show as listviews in MainActivity. Everything's done via php and json.
I want to make some sort of notifications, when a new event gets it's status changed to 1 in database then notification is send to all people who have the application. What is the best approach? Did I describe everything clearly?
I was looking through the internet and found something about GCM, but I am lost and I don't know where to start. Do you have perhaps some tutorial to achieve what I want?

Comment: for notifications you can implement the firebase notifications, and when the value change create and send notification via php, I suggest create a php file that changes the event value and send notification

Comment: To do that I'd need to create some sort of admin panel, where I'd be able to change status value of event I want, am I right?

Comment: only you can change the status right?

Comment: Yes, I was doing it manually through phpmyadmin on 000webhost

Comment: So you can create a php file that gets the event name change status to 1 and send notification, if you need I can create an answer with the thing that i do to send notification to my app users when go-ahead phrase changes

Comment: It'd be great if you could do that, so I could see how does it look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to send a **notification** on go-ahead phrase changes, i created this **php** file:

```
<?php
define("servername","your_servername");
define("username","your_username");
define("password","your_password");
define("dbname","your_dbname");

define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', your_API_Key' );

$topic = "/topics/todos";
$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

$exists=0;
$frasenova=$_POST['frase'];
$autornovo=$_POST['autor'];

$conn =new mysqli(servername, username, password, dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {

  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

}else{
    $sqlquery="SELECT * FROM frase_dia WHERE id='1'";

$stmt=$conn->prepare($sqlquery);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $frase, $autor);
while($stmt->fetch()) 
{
    $exists=$exists+1;
}

if($exists==1){
    //if row exists
    $sqlupdate="UPDATE frase_dia SET frase='".$frasenova."', autor='".$autornovo."' WHERE id='1'";

    $stmt=$conn->prepare($sqlupdate) or trigger_error($conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);  
    $stmt->execute() or trigger_error($stmt->error, E_USER_ERROR);

    //notification
    $fields = array (
        'to' => $topic,
        'notification' => array (
                "body" => $frasenova."\n\n".$autornovo,
                "title" => "Frase do dia",
                "sound"=> "default"
        ),
        'data' => array(
            "frase" => $frasenova,
            "autor"=> $autornovo,
            "tiponotificacao"=> 1
        )
);
}else{
    //if row not exists
    $sqlnew="INSERT INTO frase_dia (frase, autor) VALUES ('$frasenova','$autornovo')";
    $stmt=$conn->prepare($sqlnew) or trigger_error($conn->error, E_USER_ERROR); 
    $stmt->execute() or trigger_error($stmt->error, E_USER_ERROR);
    echo 'adicionado (novo)';

    //notification
    $fields = array (
        'to' => $topic,
        'notification' => array (
                "body" => $frasenova."\n\n".$autornovo,
                "title" => "Frase do dia",
                "sound"=> "default",
                "click_action"=> "inicio"
        ),
        'data' => array(
            "frase" => $frasenova,
            "autor"=> $autornovo,
            "tiponotificacao"=> 1
        )
);
}

$fields = json_encode ( $fields );
$headers = array (
        'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields );

$result = curl_exec ( $ch );
curl_close ( $ch );

echo'<div>
<svg style="width:48px;height:48px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path fill="#a62a2a" d="M21,7L9,19L3.5,13.5L4.91,12.09L9,16.17L19.59,5.59L21,7Z" />
</svg>
<br>
<font size="+2">';
    echo 'Conteúdo&nbsp;adicionado';
echo'</font>
<br><br>
</div>';
}

?>
```

And this **HTML** file:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Frase do dia</title>
<!--Import Google Icon Font-->
      <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <!--Import materialize.css-->
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>

      <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

      <style>
   /* label focus color */
   .input-field input[type=text]:focus + label {
     color: #a62a2a;
   }
   /* label underline focus color */
   .input-field input[type=text]:focus {
     border-bottom: 1px solid #a62a2a;
     box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #a62a2a;
   }
   .input-field textarea[class=materialize-textarea]:focus + label {
color: #a62a2a;
}
   .input-field textarea[class=materialize-textarea]:focus {
border-bottom: 1px solid #a62a2a;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #a62a2a;
}

      </style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#F2F2F2">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
      <div style="margin-left:20%; margin-right:20%; background-color:#FFF; border-radius:5px; margin-bottom:25px;">
      <h1 style="text-align:center; padding-top:10px;">Frase do dia</h1>
      <div class="row">
    <form class="col s12" action="adicionar_frase.php" method="post">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input id="frase" type="text" name="frase" required>
          <label for="frase">Frase</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input id="autor" type="text" name="autor" required>
          <label for="autor">Autor</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button style="display:block; margin:auto" class="btn waves-effect waves-light red darken-3" type="submit" name="Adicionar">Adicionar
  </button>

    </form>
  </div>
  <div style="width:100%; height:5px;"></div>
   </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

So what i do is send the form data in **HTML** file to the **php** file and in php file change the phrase in mysql database table and if change is **sucessfully** i create and send nottification to my users.

You can adapt these code to your Project any question just ask.